# Define agent in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I don't have access to Global Jenkins Configuration ,
because is a shared pipeline and would like to ask you if you know a way to define an agent  (Virtual machine in Azure in this case)
directly in the Jenkins Declarative or scripted pipeline